# Java - Add Element to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, position, element, addition

Looked around, couldn't find any similar questions in java..

Basically I need to add a number to an int array in a specific position index

I can only use Arrays, no `ArrayLists`

Here is what I have so far, and I know why it doesn't work, but I can't figure out how to fix that problem of overwriting, which I don't want it to do.

The task is a non-overwriting insert. e.g. the final result would be

```
[1 2 1337 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
public void main(String[] args)
{
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
array = add(array, 2, 1337);
for(int i : array)
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}


public int[] add(int[] myArray, int pos, int n)
{
    for (int i = pos; i<myArray.length-1; i++){
        myArray[i] = myArray[i+1];
    }
    myArray[pos] = n;
    return myArray;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  *"I can't figure out how to fix that problem."*  What is the problem? Note that "doesn't work" is of no use in describing the problem.  What is your best *theory* on solving it?  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Do you mean a non-overwriting insert?  e.g. the final result would be [1 2 1337 3 4 5 6 7 8]?

Comment: that problem, being the fact that it isn't adding it to the array, and that was my best theory on solving it... @Bill Yes

Comment: OK, again.  Is this homework?  If so, it should be tagged as such, and would attract more 'followers' than the last 4 tags combined.  Aaah yes.  288 (last 4 tags combined followers) vs. 862 (homework).  ;)

Comment: Then wouldn't you need to resize the target array? The original has 8 elements, and the new has 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this loop:

```
for (int i = pos; i<myArray.length-1; i++){
    myArray[i] = myArray[i+1];
}
```

It is writing `i+1` into `i` - ie it moves element *down* - you need it to move them *up*. In order to move up, you need to iterate *down* (otherwise you overwrite what you just wrote).
Try this:

```
for (int i = myArray.length - 1; i > pos; i--) {
    myArray[i] = myArray[i - 1];
}
```

Note that this will make room for the insertion at `pos` by losing (overwriting) the last element.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed this loop to do, now I can continue with my project thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray[i+1] = myArray[i];
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: That will end up replacing the rest of the array with myArray[i], which overwrites the data.